# CData from ksoap2 android

Tags: android, ksoap2, cdata

I want to send cdata from ksoap2 in android. Actually I could successfully able to send the web service request and getting the response. I need to send an cdata. I tried to send cdata as string and failed please help

Answer (score 1):

Use 
   `SoapObject.setInnerText("...");`

Everything in setInnerText will be treated as CDATA and not altered by the XMLparser.